# Is alert notification possible to access through SMS/app notification?

Tags: discussion, support, notifications

Suppose in travel (or) out of system access. At that time any one access my posted answer they ask any question regarding that means. How will I communicate with them? Is there any possible way to access via SMS? If it is available means how to active to mobile. Is any application available in the store?

Comment: Stack Overflow has good support for mobile browsers. That's probably the way to go

Comment: imagining posts and comments spelled in smspk sends shivers down my spine

Comment: Well, the request itself still has merit IMO. Being *notified* by short message isn't a completely outlandish idea.

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags: But then you'd need a two-way-system, including answering via SMS, otherwise you don't need notifications. Also that would need revers-charge (receiver pays for the SMS) or a bank-account/credit-card/paypal-account which can be billed...it might not be an outlandish idea, but it is one hell to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, it is possible. You'd need a server which gets (`curl`) your inbox on a regular basis (`cron`), your inbox should be accessible via this address for example:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/inbox/genuwine
```

From there you can parse the data (pretty slick JSON if I see that correct) and check for new messages (`isNew`-field). Those you can simply rely through your SMS-Gateway directly to your mobilephone. The problem is that I do not know how the system marks those as read, but I think fetching the inbox does that.

Now, answering via SMS is a little bit tricky, as you'd need to build up a session, maintain that, find the question and figure out how to post a comment/answer...how good are you with `curl`?

---

Oh, you wanted a ready and done solution...no, there isn't one. If you don't have a data plan on your mobilephone, you're out of luck.